# How to change the icon of a clickonce installer?

Tags: .net, installation, icons, clickonce

When I publish my application I get a .application file and a setup.exe - is it possible to change the icon of the setup.exe?

Answer (score 2):

If setup.exe does not have a digital signature you can use resource editor to replace the default icon with the icon you want. [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) can do this.

If setup.exe is digitally signed, you will have to remove the signature before editing the file and sign it once again after editing resources.